# Algorithm that asks for numbers until zero is input

Tags: c

I'm trying to make an algorithm in C that asks you to input any number, and stops asking when you input the number 0. I'm supposed to do it with a while loop, but it doesn't work and I tried everything I've learned. This is my code that doesn't work:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number;
    while(number != 0)
    {
        printf("Introduce a number: ");
        scanf("%i",&number);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should initialize `number` to a value *different* from 0 to enter the loop. It's also a good idea to check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: You're using `number` without previously having assigned it a value. Try initialization: `int number = 42;`

Comment: https://ideone.com/MBRUCP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign a number to `number` before using it in the condition.

You have two options: a) use a dummy initial value, or b) scanf before test

```
// a) dummy value
int number = 42;
while (number != 0) { /* ... */ }
```

or

```
// b) scanf before test
int number; // uninitialized
do {
    if(scanf("%i", &number) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} while (number != 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully it's not too late to bring my two cents to the party.

The solution which others suggest is definitely possible and working solution, however, I think it can be done in a slightly neater way. For cases like this, `do while` statement exists:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number; // Doesn't need to be initialized in this case
    do {
        printf("Introduce a number: ");
        if (scanf("%i", &number) != 1) { // If the value couldn't be read, end the loop
            number = 0;
        }
    } while (number != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

The reason I think this solution is better is just that it doesn't bring any other magic constants to the code, hence it should be better readable.

If someone saw `int number = 42;`, for example, he'd be asking - Why 42? Why is the initial value 42? Is this value used somewhere? The answer is: No, it is not, thus it's not necessary to have it there.

Comment: "Doesn't need", if you have a valid input, but that's not always the case: https://ideone.com/tfNC3x . Better safe then sorry: https://ideone.com/QVaZvc

Comment: @Bob__: you really **really** should check the return value of `scanf()` rather than relying on it not messing with the argument in case of error. I mean: in the 2nd ideone, after `scanf()` returns `0` or `EOF` there is no guarantee `number` is still zero.

Comment: @Bob__ That's a great point, I've edited the answer. As @pmg noted, setting a default value still isn't the best approach of fixing this issue. The documentation of `scanf()` doesn't state what it does with the value when the stream cannot be read. Thus your solution introduces UB.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int number = 1;
 while(number != 0){

    printf("Introduce a number: ");
    scanf("%i",&number);
 }
```

Scanf will pause loop and waiting for typing a number